# Access List of Files in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have a list of Markdown files in a folder that is copied over via Grunt, that I would like my AngularJS project to be able to list out in my view. (e.g. files 1.md, 2.md, 3.md in folder /foo/ -- I would like a list such as ["1.md","2.md","3.md"] to be used in the actual ng project.)

I figure this would require a Grunt job to be able to read the list of files in the folder, and dump the list of file names to a JSON object or something the Angular controller could read and bind.

I have tried various things and nothing seems to net quite what I want. If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read files names: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

Generate dump and append it to some JavaScript file: https://github.com/mattstyles/grunt-banner